# Why is there a compound highlighted in red in a KEGG Module search?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, cell-biology, database, data

Considering the following module: 
http://www.kegg.jp/kegg-bin/show_module?M00115+C00003 
why is the compound C00003 marked in red?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just a way of highlighting your search term. If you search [M00115+C03722](http://www.kegg.jp/kegg-bin/show_module?M00115+C03722), you will see C03722 in red.

Comment: where did you search using this syntax?

Comment: @Rishika On the browser address bar. You can also do that by going to the KEGG home page and searching.

Comment: no data found, did you use this exact syntax " M00115+C03722" ??

Comment: @Rishika Just click on the link. If you want to see the actual link just right click and select "copy link location". The syntax is same as the link you posted in the question. I just replaced C00003 with C03722.